# Can i add custom code in Source in specific page, Header from function.php?

Tags: plugins, php

there are many plugins that do some job but can i add custom code per page? Also i mean specific code by pages,posts? with function.php?
For example, that code will appear every page:

```
function hook_link() {
    ?>
        <link href="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Buhehe.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_link');
```

Can i make something like this with function.php for every page customed and specified?

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions in you function if you want to add icons like this method you mentioned in question.

```
function hook_link() {

  global $post;
  if ($post->post_type == 'page' && $post->ID == 'whatever page id') {
    echo '<link href="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Buhehe.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">';
  }
  ?>

  <?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'hook_link');
```

to check page or post etc you can use [is_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page) and [is_single()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Post_Page) functions.

Comment: What is page id? how can i generate it for each pages or posts?

Comment: var_dump($post); you will get ID from there or another post attributes etc like type from $post->post_type

Comment: How can i exatyle emplement this in function.php. for example this is a one simple post: http://buhehe.de/ikea-verwandelt-ein-wohnzimmer-in-einen-diy-plattenladen-kallax-regal/
Where can i find its id?

Comment: edit this post in admin are and you can get post id or see functions provided in above links in answer or var_dump($post) in that code on your local environment to see ID. Above is example you can pass conditions accordingly and see links https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page  and https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Post_Page

Comment: in admin area this post has this url:http://buhehe.de/wp-admin/post.php?post=289&action=edit